# Removing Notes from ADFS Relying Party with Set-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust PowerSell command?

Tags: powershell, adfs, adfs4.0

I actually want to complete a simple task by PowerShell in ADFS 4.0:
Setting a note for a relying party.

This actually works fine like this:

`Set-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust -TargetName SomeRelyingParty -Notes SomeNote`

The problem is, that I can't set it back to an empty string, because I get this eror message:
`Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Notes'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.`

I also tried `""` or `$null` as a parameter, which results in the same error message.

My workaround so far is setting `" "`, but still it is space character and not an empty string as I want it to be. 
Once a note is set, the only way to fully remove the note again, is by doing so in the ADFS user interface, I couldn't figure out, how to do this by scripting it.

**Update**

I still couldn't figure out a solution, so I contacted our Microsoft Principal Consultant, he came up with the solution setting backtick (`) and zero (0) under quotes (which I cannot write here, as backtick is also a stackoverflow syntax - however this is escpaed). Still there will be an "empty" String with the length of 1.

I think now, that this is actually a bug, so I asked him to contact the ADFS product team.